# How can I put an svg inside of a span and get the span to envelop the svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I put an svg inside of a span and get the span to envelop the svg? For example, here I want two black circles with gray background side by side. I just can't get it to work.

```
<span style="background: gray">               
    <svg height="100" width="100" style="display: block">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" ></circle>
    </svg>
</span>        

<span style="background: gray">               
    <svg height="100" width="100" style="display: block">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" ></circle>
    </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: why span and not div?

Comment: because I need result to be side-by-side, not stacked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a CSS rule to make the span that is `display: inline` by default be `display: inline-block`.

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4maotyv4/

Comment: Yes. Until now I was unaware of inline-block. Thank you very much.

Comment: HTML elements have defaults that people forget. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following solution

```html
<span style="background: gray; display: inline-block">               
    <svg height="100" width="100" style="display: block">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" ></circle>
    </svg>
</span>        

<span style="background: gray; display: inline-block">               
    <svg height="100" width="100" style="display: block">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" ></circle>
    </svg>
</span>
```

Comment: Perfect. I was unaware of inline-block. Thank you very much.